# How do I print from registers in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bios

First I must state I am BRAND NEW to ASM.

I have an example of moving a character to AL and printing that to the screen:

```
mov al, 041h
int 10h                 
mov al, 042h
int 10h
mov al, 043h
int 10h
ret
```

This prints ABC to screen.

How can I do something similar with moving these 3 characters to another register instead? Such as DL.

Comment: If you're just learning asm, are you sure you want to learn 16-bit x86 with legacy-BIOS function calls?  You could just learn 32 or 64-bit x86, or another ISA like ARM.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  Writing asm by hand was more common many years ago, back in 16-bit x86 days, and some people mistakenly associate asm with 16-bit x86.  (e.g. you only tagged this assembly, leaving out the required tags to say what kind of assembly.)

Comment: if x86 I highly recommend 8088/6 first with dos calls.  But if new to asm learn something like msp430 or arm (thumb) or pdp11 (very serious that is IMO the preferred first if not msp430) on a simulator where you cant brick the thing and have to buy another.

Comment: google "ralf brown interrupt list".  As Peter pointed out in the answer each call has very specific rules as to which registers must be used for passing and returning information on a per interrupt basis.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do something similar with moving these 3 characters to another register instead? Such as DL.

You can't.

`int 10h` functions have a fixed calling convention.  You pass them arguments in the registers where they want them.  So `mov al,dl`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H. You need to set a function code in AH first, like `mov ah, 0Eh` / `int 10h` for the "teletype output" function.  (In text mode, it only looks at AL.  The documentation also mentions a page-number and color in BX, but you're not using that.)

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @Abacus: if it answered your question completely, you can mark it as accepted with the checkbox under the vote arrows.

Answer (score 1):

> This prints ABC to screen.

The code that you've shown can only do this if we assume that `AH=0Eh`, the identifying number for the BIOS Teletype function.

> How can I do **something similar** with moving these 3 characters to another register instead? Such as DL.

You can!

Apart from the BIOS API (`int 10h`) there's also the DOS API (`int 21h`).
If you put the characters - one at a time - in the `DL` register, the [DOS Character Output function 02h](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah02) will also print them on the screen and with the additional benefit that you don't have to worry about the DisplayPage number in `BH` or the CharacterColor in `BL`.

```
mov ah, 02h      ;DOS Character Output
mov dl, 41h
int 21h                 
mov dl, 42h
int 21h
mov dl, 43h
int 21h
```

The answer by Peter Cordes obviously remains correct.

> **"You can not freely chose which registers you use to request any API function."**

### A note about hexadecimal numbers.

In an instruction like `mov al, 041h`, prefixing the hexadecimal number with a **0** is redundant and - for me at least - it reduces readability somewhat.
You only should zero-prefix the hexadecimal numbers that would otherwise start with a letter, so those that begin with 'A'...'F'.